# Handle out of range in select

Tags: python, linux, ipc, pipe

Many (>1000) workers (process) do some and want to save their work results in database. Result of work is JSON object. Workers produce JSON objects 1-5 per second. Database saver is separated process. Unidirectional connections for transfer JSON object from worker to saver is multiprocessing.Pipe. Number of pipes equal number of workers.

In saver process periodically сall:

```
def recv_data(self):
    data = []
    for pipe in self.data_pipe_pool:
        if pipe.poll():
            data.append(pipe.recv())
    return data
```

self.data_pipe_pool - list of pipes from workers.

All work fine if i run ~100 workers. If i run >1000 workers i get exception:

```
2013-02-13T15:17:40.731429
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "saver.py", line 44, in run
    profile = self.poll_data()
  File "saver.py", line 116, in poll_data
    ret = self.recv_data()
  File "saver_unit.py", line 127, in recv_data
    if pipe.poll():
IOError: handle out of range in select()
```

I know that this is due with `select()` call and that:

> FD_SETSIZE is usually defined to 1024 in GNU/Linux systems

But where called `select`? If in `pipe.poll()`, why I exceed the FD_SETSIZE limit, i'm calling `pipe.poll()` for 1 pipe individually? Where can i watch python language sources with this call `select`?

What workaround not exceed `FD_SETSIZE` limit or not use `select`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [`select` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select), you will see that:

> Executing FD_CLR() or FD_SET() with a value of fd that is negative or is equal to or larger than FD_SETSIZE will result in undefined behavior.

This means that if `select` is used behind the scene in your `poll` call (which seems likely), and you have file descriptors larger than `FD_SETSIZE` (very likely if you have over 1000 pipes) then the result can be anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
How i can avoid shadow calling `select`? May be exist pipe (or over object) with epoll api in low level?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever thought of using something like [beanstalkd](https://github.com/earl/beanstalkc) as it sounds like you've got one pipe from worker to server, whereas typically you'd have 1000's of workers and then 10's of servers reading from a results queue to store them in a database.

The benefit being that it's likely that your workers are taking a lot more time doing their work than talking to the server, yet you've got a pipe open to that server.

You could have a 'job-queue' that your 1000's of workers take from and a 'results-queue' that they store results on. Thereafter you could have many servers taking from the 'results-queue' to store in the DB.

Which is a long way of saying "at least then you'd not run out of file handles".

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using epoll. Solution is very simple:

```
def set_data_pipe_poll(self, data_pipe_poll):
    self.epoll = select.epoll()
    for p in data_pipe_poll:
        self.epoll.register(p, select.EPOLLIN)
    self.data_pipe_poll = data_pipe_poll

def recv_data(self):
    data = []
    events = self.epoll.poll(timeout = 0)
    for fileno, _ in events:
        p = filter(lambda x: x.fileno() == fileno, self.data_pipe_poll)[0]
        data.append(p.recv())
    return data
```

When i call `epoll.poll()` i not call `select`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I used multiprocessing.Queue for each worker and when number of workers was about 600, methods of queue failed with `IOError: handle out of range in select()`.

I found [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue10527) in official bug tracker that caused the problem. It was fixed in 2.7.4 (I had 2.7.3). Updating of python package solved the problem.